# System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography - No Parameterless Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sqlgeography

I have a submission page where one of the form's fields are lat/long coordinates. I store them in a System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography called 'Location', and render the fields like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.Longitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location.Longitude)
                <img class="load-icon" src="~/Content/Loading.gif" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.Longitude)
            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.Latitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location.Latitude)
                <img class="load-icon" src="~/Content/Loading.gif" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.Latitude)
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my controller, I receive the form on the other side:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "...Location...")] Report report)
```

But every time I POST with the values from the form it throws an exception, stating that some object (it fails to tell me which) does not have a parameter less constructor. When I remove 'Location' from the bind string but keep all of the other properties (omitted in my sample), it works fine.

That seems to indicate that the issue is that it's trying to create a DbGeography to put in to 'report', but failing because it can't instantiate it. Is this correct? If so, how can I avoid this error? I would rather not use a custom class in my database, but I can't think of any other options.

Comment: Has DBGeography a default constructor?

Comment: it s not public constructor with no arguments

Comment: so, if this is not public constructor, what your expectation - this is your answer

Answer (score 0):

the best way it's to use a sqlQueryCommand 
this the code 100% worked :

```
    var id = form["id"];
            var name = form["name"];
            var lat = form["Location.Latitude"];
            var lng = form["Location.Longitude"];
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[schoolinfo] values ('" + id + "','" + name + "',geography::Point(" + lat + ", " + lng + ", 4326))");
```

Comment: No, that's not safe at all, dont do this.

Comment: why not ? @JOSEFtw

Comment: i have problem to binding a dbGeography so i choose formcollection and sqCommand